# Can IoT device with different protocols use IoT Agents to "talk" with each other?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm playing around with FIWARE Orion, IoT Agent JSON, and IoT Agent OPC UA. I'm wondering that since all the IoT Agents connect with Orion and map different IoT protocols into NGSI, is it possible for devices using different protocols to communicate with each other without adding any additional application logic?

Let's consider a MQTT device A and an OPC UA server B, For example, is it possible for:

1. B reports its measurements to the Orion Context Broker, A subscribe to that attribute. Some thing like 
   B-->IoT Agent OPC UA-->Orion-->IoT Agent JSON-->mosquitto-->A
   (I tried to make a context provider registration. However, the url of the B entity attributes(`orion:1026/v2/B/attrs/XXX`) obviously doesn't work since Orion will send POST to an `orion:1026/v2/B/attrs/XXX/op/query` which doesn't exist), and the provided attribute is not provisioned at IoT Agent JSON...I feel like I'm taking the totally wrong direction)
2. A and B access the same entity and report their measurements to that entity in the Orion. Since A and B both need their own IoT Agents, and the same entity can not be provisioned at each agent due to duplicated...

Is it a super bad idea that trying to mess up one entity with several protocols' devices...Thank you so much for answering my doubts in advance!!!

Comment: Maybe adding a diagram (showing A, B, etc.) would be very clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each NGSI entity should map to *something that has state in the real world*. In your case your data models should be based on [Device](https://fiware-datamodels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Device/Device/doc/spec/index.html) and you should have a separate OPC-UA-based **Device** entity and a second separate JSON **Device** entity.  These are the low level entities within your system, which would hold readings from the IoT Devices and would also hold additional data (such as battery-level or a link to the documentation or whatever).

If you want to model the state of a second aggregated entity then you can do that as well - just [subscribe](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#subscriptions) to changes in context in the device and **Upsert** the values and metadata over to the other entity.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:1027/v2/subscriptions/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'fiware-service: openiot' \
--data-raw '{
  "description": "Notify Subscription Listener of Lamp context changes",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": "Lamp.*"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": ["luminosity"]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://tutorial:3000/device/subscription/luminosity"
    },
    "attrs": ["luminosity", "controlledAsset", "supportedUnits"]
  },
  "throttling": 5
}'
```

Sample code to do the work from the listening endpoint ( `/device/subscription/luminosity` ) can be found [here](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Step-by-Step/blob/master/context-provider/controllers/ngsi-ld/device-convert.js) - it is a tutorial which is still a work-in-progress, so the full documentation is currently missing.

```js
function shadowDeviceMeasures(req, res) {
  const attrib = req.params.attrib;

  async function copyAttributeData(device, index) {
    await upsertDeviceEntityAsLD(device);
    if (device[attrib]) {
      await upsertLinkedAttributeDataAsLD(device, 'controlledAsset', attrib);
    }
  }

  req.body.data.forEach(copyAttributeData);
  res.status(204).send();
}
```

The point here is that you can (and should) think of data entities at different levels -

- I have a thermometer **Device** - it is sending temperature readings. It has a `temperature` attribute
- I have a **Building** - it has a thermometer in it - the **Building** has a `temperature` attribute *and* `metadata.providedBy` linking back to the **Device**

Depending on your use case you may only need to consider entities at one layer or you may need to use both.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the suggestions! I think that thinking of entities at different levels should be the direction for my doubts! Is there any examples or tutorial about this `metadata.providedBy` feature? Is this NGSI v2 or NGSI LD? In your example, will it be poosible that if I query **Building** about `temperature` attribute and the response shows the actual value from the **Device**?

Comment: The [Working-with-Linked-Data](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Working-with-Linked-Data) tutorial is not yet completed - I haven't written up the commentary. The code you are looking for can  be found [here](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Step-by-Step/blob/master/context-provider/controllers/ngsi-ld/device-convert.js).

The equivalent for NGSI-v2 was covered during the [Malaga Bootcamp](https://github.com/jason-fox/malaga-bootcamp)